# Python - Replace newline with return carriage/newline in file output

Tags: python

First of I've only been writing python for a couple of months

Seconly, I have a txt file that needs to be processed. In order for it to be processed properly each lines has to end with '\r\n'.

However, that is not always tha case, sometimes it onle contains the '\n' (newline).

Therefore, I need to check the file and if the '\r\n' is missing replace '\n' with '\r\n'.

I have tried a couple of ways and failed.

First I tried the following:

```
with open("initial_file.txt",'rb') as file_content:
  #1253 is a Windows code page used to write modern Greek.
  mycon = file_content.read().decode('cp1253')

if (mycon.count("\r\n") == 0) and (mycon.count("\n") > 0):
  with open("destination_file.txt",'w') as file_replace:
     file_replace.write(mycon.replace("\n", "\r\n").encode('cp1253'))
```

But instead of replacing '\n' with '\r\n' I got '\r\r\n'.

So I tried another approach:

```
rf = open("initial_file.txt", 'rb')
wf = open("destination_file.txt",'wb')
mycon = rf.read().decode('cp1253')
if (mycon.count('\r\n') == 0) and (mycon.count('\n') > 0):
    for line in rf:
        newline = line.rstrip('\n')
        wf.write(newline).encode('cp1253')
        wf.write('\r\n').encode('cp1253')
```

It worked the first time and then it didn't.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong and I could appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) function from the [`io` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html). There you can specify the newline mode explicitly. Every `'\n'` is translated to `'\r\n'` in this example:

```
from io import open
with open("test.txt", "w+", newline="\r\n") as f:
    f.write(u"Hello World\n")
```

Here is the file content (`0d 0a` corresponds to `\r\n`:

```
$ hexdump -C test.txt
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f  72 6c 64 0d 0a           |Hello World..|
```

For conversion of an existing file to use a specific line termination pattern, you can read the lines while taking advantage of the [*universal newlines*](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) approach. Then you can write the lines using the explicitly specified line terminator for the output file.

```
from io import open
with open(infname, 'r') as inf, open(outfname, "w+", newline="\r\n") as outf:
    outf.writelines(inf)
```

For reference:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open
- http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines
- http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines
- http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm!! And I'll make sure to read all of your references.

Answer (score 3):

Without the encoding dance,

```
with open("file.txt") as rf, open("out.txt", "w") as wf:
    for line in rf:
        wf.write("%s\r\n" % line.strip())
```

Context managers are cool arn't they.

Comment: same problem with my fisrt code example. For some reason I can not understand it replaces '\n' with '\r\r\n'

Comment: This answer works if you are not sure if the file has carriage returns, which is cool.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the input in binary mode, but writing the output in text mode. Text mode automatically translates newline characters to the platform-specific newline sequence. Since CP1253 has the same newline and carriage return characters as ascii and unicode, you can drop the string-replacement code and the encoding/decoding code entirely. If that weren't the case, you'd probably want to open the output in binary mode or make some other change.

```
with open("file.txt", 'rb') as rf, open("out.txt", "w") as wf:
    wf.writelines(rf)
```